# Django "request.user" always returns "AnonymousUser" even though sessionid gets added and is valid

Tags: python, django, authentication, oauth-2.0, discord

So I made a discord oauth2 login without using a User model like AbstractUser or AbstractBaseModel, when I first made it a month ago, it worked fine and the login worked flawlessly! (Profile loaded, username shown, etc.) I don't know what I changed a week ago, but it no longer works. The custom authentication works and authenticate() returns a new DiscordUser model, then it gets passed to login() with the custom backend argument. The sessionid gets saved in the cookie storage when I check it. When I also check the DB, the sessionid is there and therefore a valid sessionid. Yet when I print out the request.user or request.user.is_authenticated I always get AnonymousUser and False. I don't understand. I followed this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KKJyU7JGuVk&list=PLwu1p7jK5YEUhRNJpzLYa8nhWRnJdPR6p

auth.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import BaseBackend
from .models import DiscordUser

class DiscordAuthenticationBackend(BaseBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, user) -> DiscordUser:
        try:
            user = DiscordUser.objects.get(pk=user["id"])
            return user
        except DiscordUser.DoesNotExist:
            new_user = DiscordUser.objects.create_discord_user(user)
            new_user.save()
            return new_user
```

managers.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import models
from datetime import datetime
from utils.cipher import XChaCha20Manager
from base64 import b64encode

class DiscordUserOAuth2Manager(models.UserManager):
    def create_discord_user(self, user):
        # encrypt tokens with the same nonce
        encrypted_access_token, nonce = XChaCha20Manager().encrypt(user["access_token"].encode())
        encrypted_refresh_token, _ = XChaCha20Manager(nonce=nonce).encrypt(user["refresh_token"].encode())

        new_user = self.create(
            user_id=user["id"],
            username = f"{user["username"]}",
            avatar = user["avatar"],
            encrypted_access_token = b64encode(encrypted_access_token).decode(),
            encrypted_refresh_token = b64encode(encrypted_refresh_token).decode(),
            encryption_nonce = b64encode(nonce).decode(),
            last_login = datetime.now(),
        )
        return new_user
```

models.py

```
from .managers import DiscordUserOAuth2Manager
from utils.cipher import XChaCha20Manager
from base64 import b64decode
from django.db import models

class VerificationSession(models.Model):
    user_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class DiscordUser(models.Model):
    objects = DiscordUserOAuth2Manager()

    user_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    avatar = models.CharField(max_length=36)

    encrypted_access_token = models.CharField(max_length=100) # stored in base64
    encrypted_refresh_token = models.CharField(max_length=100) # stored in base64
    encryption_nonce = models.CharField(max_length=100) # stored in base64

    is_premium = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    is_authenticated = True
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

    async def get_token(self, user_id: str, type: str) -> str | None:
        try:
            user = await DiscordUser.objects.aget(pk=user_id)
            match type:
                case "access":
                    return XChaCha20Manager(nonce=b64decode(user.encryption_nonce)).decrypt(b64decode(user.encrypted_access_token))
                case "refresh":
                    return XChaCha20Manager(nonce=b64decode(user.encryption_nonce)).decrypt(b64decode(user.encrypted_refresh_token))
        except DiscordUser.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpRequest, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from securifier.settings import BASE_DIR
from typing import Union
import httpx, dotenv

# Create your views here.

ENV_PATH = BASE_DIR / ".env"
CLIENT_ID = dotenv.get_key(ENV_PATH, "CLIENT_ID")
OAUTH2_REDIRECT_URI = dotenv.get_key(ENV_PATH, "OAUTH2_REDIRECT_URI")
CLIENT_SECRET = dotenv.get_key(ENV_PATH, "CLIENT_SECRET")
DISCORD_AUTH_URL = fr"https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id={CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri={OAUTH2_REDIRECT_URI}&response_type=code&scope=identify%20guilds"
DISCORD_BOT_INVITE = fr"https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id={CLIENT_ID}&permissions=8&scope=bot"


def index(request: HttpRequest) -> HttpResponse:
    print(request.user)
    print(request.user.is_authenticated)
    return render(request, "index/index.html")

def botInvite(request: HttpRequest) -> HttpResponse:
    return redirect(DISCORD_BOT_INVITE)

# Discord OAuth2 Login
def discordLogin(request: HttpRequest) -> HttpResponseRedirect:
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect("index")

    return redirect(DISCORD_AUTH_URL)

@login_required(login_url="/oauth2")
def logoutUser(request: HttpRequest) -> HttpResponseRedirect:
    logout(request)
    return redirect("index")

def exchangeOauth2Code(code) -> Union[str, None]:
    BASE_API_URI = r"https://discord.com/api/v10"
    data = {
        'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
        'code': code,
        'redirect_uri': OAUTH2_REDIRECT_URI
    }
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
    try:
        response = httpx.post(f"{BASE_API_URI}/oauth2/token", data=data, headers=headers, auth=(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET))
        response.raise_for_status()
        access_token, refresh_token = response.json()["access_token"], response.json()["refresh_token"]
        user_data = httpx.get(f"{BASE_API_URI}/users/@me", headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"})
        user_data = user_data.json()
        user_data.update({"access_token": access_token, "refresh_token": refresh_token}) # add tokens to user_data
        return user_data
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return None

def discordLoginCallback(request) -> HttpResponseRedirect:
    code = request.GET.get("code")
    user = exchangeOauth2Code(code)
    if user: # login
        discord_user = authenticate(request, user=user)
        login(request, user=discord_user, backend="index.auth.DiscordAuthenticationBackend")
        print("returning to index")
        return redirect("index")
    else:
        context = {
            "msg": "An error occurred while the OAuth2 authorization process"
        }
        return render(request, "index/message.html", context)
```

settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for securifier project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.2.6.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
from dotenv import get_key as env_get

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

ENV_PATH = BASE_DIR / ".env"


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '...'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    "index.auth.DiscordAuthenticationBackend",
]

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    "adrf", # async django rest framework
    "index",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'securifier.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            BASE_DIR / "templates"],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'securifier.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "NAME": env_get(ENV_PATH, "POSTGRE_DB_NAME"),
        "USER": env_get(ENV_PATH, "POSTGRE_DB_USERNAME"),
        "PASSWORD": env_get(ENV_PATH, "POSTGRE_DB_PASSWORD"),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Amsterdam'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = False


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static"
]

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

I've been spending hours trying to fix the issue, but I didn't get it to work.
Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the get_user() function in the custom authentication backend was missing. Adding the function to the custom auth backend solved the problem:

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import BaseBackend
from .models import DiscordUser

class DiscordAuthenticationBackend(BaseBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, user) -> DiscordUser:
        if returned_user := self.get_user(user["id"]):
            return returned_user
        else:
            new_user = DiscordUser.objects.create_discord_user(user)
            new_user.save()
            return new_user

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return DiscordUser.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except DiscordUser.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```